# Get authorized user's profile picture (Instagram Basic Display API)

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

After authorizing the user and receiving an auth_token I am able to get the fields `id`, `username`, and `account_type` for the currently authorized user.

How do I also get the profile picture for the user?

Comment: It would be great if somebody knows also how to get the `bio`.

Comment: Those items can be scraped trivially from the users Instagram page but I am so far unaware of how to do this through the official api. This is very frustrating for us since we have a policy of only using official apis

Answer (score 0):

It's frustrating but right now, there is not a way to do it through the API officially. Maybe you can use an thirdy party package to do it **scraping**.